# Replace div tag with p tag only if it does not have direct childs as p/ol/ul tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to replace div tag with p tag only if div tag doesn't contains direct child as p/ol/ul tag and if it contains p/ol/ul tag as direct child then just remove the div tag and keep the child tags as it is.

Example:

```
 <div>
      <ul>
         <li>HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 <div>
      <p>
         HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate
      </p>
  </div>
 <div>
      <strong>
         <li>HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate</li>
      </strong>
  </div>
```

Desired output:

```
  <ul>
      <li>HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
     HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate
  </p>
 <p>
      <strong>
         <li>HIPAA Privacy Module Certificate</li>
      </strong>
  </p>
```

What i'm trying but didn't work:

```
    <xsl:template match="div[not(div)]">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="ul[(parent::div)]">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>

    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ol[(parent::div)]">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ol>
    
        </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="p[(parent::div)]">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>
    
        </xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like doing

```
<xsl:template match="div[p | ol | ul]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[not(p | ol | ul)]">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the identity transformation.

Comment: can you suggest me the xsl to delete p tag inside the li tags. <li id="62592d802d9bf64743a6103f">
         <p>
            <u>
               <strong>WHAT IS CARRER DEVELOPMENT PLAIN ?</strong>
            </u>
         </p>
      </li> that will result to <li id="62592d802d9bf64743a6103f">
            <u>
               <strong>WHAT IS CARRER DEVELOPMENT PLAIN ?</strong>
            </u>
      </li>

Comment: @rajatsethi, give it a try, similar to the template above removing `div` elements. if you can't get it to work, post your attempt and how it failed as a new question.

Comment: After trying with this <xsl:template match="li[p]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
I posted a comment beacause it doesn't work. If you want me to add new question then i'll do but i think i'm close to the solution that's why i post it here.

Comment: @rajatsethi, your shown input sample doesn't seem to cover that requirement of a `p` inside an `li`, so it is a new requirement that you have come up with after an answer to the existing question has been provided.

Comment: Yes it is a new requirement. Let me add another question after giving it a try. Thanks martin

Comment: Can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996195/verify-href-has-a-valid-url-or-not-xslt-1?noredirect=1#comment127219728_71996195