# Verify href has a valid url or not xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to validate the url inside href tag. If that url is valid then do nothing else remove that href tag inside `<a>` tag. We can use any general regex or any other kind of url validation to do this that validates the href.

Example:

```
<a href="http://" rel="nofollow">tinyurl</a>
 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" rel="nofollow">valid url</a>
 <a href="https://fanyi.baidu.com/?aldtype=16047###" rel="nofollow">invalid url</a>
```

Result:

```
 <a rel="nofollow">tinyurl</a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" rel="nofollow">valid url</a>
 <a rel="nofollow">invalid url</a>
```

Thanks in advance. Any clue/help given is appreciated.
regex that can be helpful:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

Comment: Define 'valid'. Do you mean 'syntactically correct', or 'working'?

Comment: Valid only means that it should be syntactically correct. Which means it should be a proper valid url does'nt matter the url works or not.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? Have you checked whether it supports an extension function using regular expression or whether it allows you to call into the underlying platform like .NET or Java or PHP to use regular expression functions from that platform?

Comment: @MartinHonnen i can add an extension to my stylesheet and also FYI i'm using java with xsl <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: If you are using Java but prefer to use XSLT 1 with Xalan instead of XSLT 2 or 3 with Saxon then look into the extensions Xalan provides https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#exslt_ext or allows.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for this but i don't have much idea about xalan. Still in learning process. I'll look more deeply into this one. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you thought about scripting?  msxsl:script   You just have to be careful about allowing it because it can cause a security risk...

Answer (score 0):

Michael Sperberg-McQueen has defined XSD types that match different flavours of URI in

http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-URI-RFC3986.xsd

and

http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-IRI-RFC3987.xsd

To see the way these complex regular expressions are constructed, view these documents at the raw XML level using (for example) curl.

Regular expressions can be used for pattern matching in XSLT 2.0, but there's no support in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the related links but i have gone through the official doc i know there is no support for regex in xslt 1 but what i'm looking for is something similar to regex which might be helpful for my solution.

Comment: There is no way in XSLT 1.0 of validating that a string is a valid URI, other than calling out to an extension function, which will be processor dependent.